# Show that $\omega + \omega$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Two sets are equinumerous if there exists a bijection between them. A set is finite if it is equinumerous to some $n \in \omega$ and a set is countable if it is equinumerous to $\omega$.

$\omega$ is the set of all natural numbers as an ordinal.

How can I prove $\omega+\omega$ is countable? Where $+$ is the ordinal addition.

Comment: Any suggestions on your part?

Comment: Can you show, for instance, that $\omega+3$ is countable? Or that the set of odd integers is countable?

Comment: Start by looking at what $\omega + \omega$ *is*. Write it out and see if you can number the elements.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo In fact I don't even know where to begin. Usually my way to construct the bijection is first visualize the sets and see the correspondence between the elements. But what does $\omega+\omega$ looks like?

Comment: @mephistolotl That's where I get stuck. I don't know what does it look like.

Comment: I presume $+$ denotes sumset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset

Comment: Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem

Comment: @FredrikSavje No, it's ordinal sum.

Comment: @bbw $\omega + \omega = (1, 2, 3, \ldots, 1', 2', 3', \ldots)$. Find a way to enumerate its elements and remember that you're looking for a bijection, not a order-isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\omega+\omega=\omega\cup\{\omega+n:n\in\omega\}
$$
and $\omega=\{2n:n\in\omega\}\cup\{1+2n:n\in\omega\}$

Comment: you mean map n to 2n for $n \in \omega$ and map each $\omega + n$ to $1+2n$?

Comment: @bbw That's a possible idea

Answer (score 0):

ω + ω is like the set of all ω + n for any n ∈ ℕ. So to map it onto ω we would map ω onto 0, ω + 1 onto 1 and so on, seeing as there’s a bijection, it must be countable.

Comment: It's great that you found out this site. But please note the dates and other answers before you add your answers. You should preferably format your answers with MathJax, which is a $\rm\LaTeX$-like system. And finally, this answer is wrong, since $\omega+\omega$ is not "like $\omega+n$", that would just be $\omega$. It is like *two* copies of $\omega$, as suggested by egreg in his answer.

Comment: When I say ω + n, I mean the nth successor ordinal of ω, not as in actual addition. And ω + ω (sometimes ω2) is the limit ordinal of the set of successor ordinals of ω. I’m pretty sure of that fact. And I can quote Wikipedia on that!

Comment: ‘(Exactly what addition means will be defined later on: just consider them as names.) After all of these come ω·2 (which is ω+ω)’ - Wikipedia

Comment: $\omega+n$ *is* actual addition. It's awesome that you're enthusiastic about set theory and ordinals, it really is, but I suggest that you study it properly, not from Wikipedia.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Start by reading http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf